# In python how Print total number of columns that contain null values & also print the column names of null to a csv output file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Got a csv file with a few columns and the data contains null values for certain column. using pandas dataframe function, how can I Print the total number of columns that contain null values & null column names to a output csv file?

Output.csv
2 # no of columns
Column a
Column b

Comment: can you add a sample dataframe and the expected output too? thanks

Comment: item no, city, state, total_sales                                                                                          expected output to a csv file.                                                                                    
2 # no of columns

Column a

Column c

Comment: no no no,, you should definately check this for any future questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code that will help you attain the above:

```
    df=pd.DataFrame({'Name':["abc","def",None],'Age':[1,None,3],'Address':["rst","uvw","xyz"]})

    null_colname=df.columns[df.isnull().any()].tolist() #find columns which returns True for null testing and convert the column names to list
    null_colnum=len(null_colname)                       # take length of the above list

    p=str(null_colnum)+"# of columns:"                  # initialize string in the format of required output
    for i in range(0,null_colnum):                      #iterate over the list
        p=p+'Column-'+null_colname[i]+' '               # concatenate column names to the string


    text_file = open(filepath+"Output.csv", "w")        #export to csv
    text_file.write("%s" % p)
    text_file.close()
```

Comment: Thank you Rimil. How to adjust the output.csv so it outputs # of columns in a row and the column names in each row separately.?

Comment: As per my understanding, you want the first row to be the # of columns and the respective rows be the column names. You can do it it following ways: `code`list_col=list(null_colname)

    
text_file = open(filepath+"Output.csv", "w")        #export to csv
text_file.write(p)
text_file.write("\n")
for col_name in list_col:
    text_file.write(col_name)
    text_file.write("\n")
    
text_file.close() `code`  or you can convert this to dataframe 'code' df_final=pd.DataFrame()   
df_final[p]=list_col

df_final.to_csv(filepath+"\\output.csv",index=False) `code`

Answer (score 1):

I prepared the test data as follows:

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(size=(5, 10)), columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJ'))
df[df > 0.9] = pd.np.nan; df
```

To get column names containig *NaN* values, run:

```
nn = df.isnull().any()
```

For my test data, the result is:

```
A     True
B    False
C    False
D     True
E    False
F    False
G    False
H     True
I     True
J    False
dtype: bool
```

We are actually interested in index values where the value is *True*.
To get them, run:

```
nullCols = nn.index[nn].tolist()
```

The result is:

```
['A', 'D', 'H', 'I']
```

And to get the number of such columns, run:

```
len(nullCols)
```

The result is `4`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
pd.DataFrame({'Columns': a.columns[a.isnull().any()], 'Count':len([x for x in a.isnull().any().values if x == True])}).to_csv('myfilepath.csv')
```

Where a is your dataframe name, and change any() to all() is you want to check whether or not the whole column is empty or not.

Comment: how do i export this to a csv?

Comment: edited: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html